# PLSQL: IF EXISTS in stored procedure while using loop

Tags: arrays, loops, plsql

I am new to PLSQL. I am trying to create a procedure which iterates through an array.

My requirement is if one of the value is not found in table, it should add into FAILARRAY, otherwise it should add into PASSARRAY.

I was getting no data found exception even if it is handled, it goes out of the loop and next value in the loop is not getting iterated again.

Is there any way we can use if exists command here. Please help.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SCHEMA.PR_VALIDATE
(
FILEARRAY IN STRARRAY,
PASSARRAY OUT STRARRAY,
FAILARRAY OUT STRARRAY,
)
IS 
--DECLARE
fileName VARCHAR2 (50);
fileId NUMBER;

BEGIN
    for i in 1 .. FILEARRAY.count
       loop
        fileName := FILEARRAY(i); 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (FILEARRAY (i));
        SELECT FILEID into fileId FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE FILENAME=fileName;
        end loop
END;
```

Comment: Can you not use `if FILEARRAY.exists(i) then` ... `end if;`? The Oracle documentation for this method is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#CJAEFFID).

Comment: Actually i dont want to check if file array contains values, i need to check that in Database table if an entry is there for that in the table..In general cases, it was handled using Exception handling NO DATA FOUND. But in my case lets say that, i have 8 values in array..And for third value, no data found in table. it will come to exception block. Now i wont be able to iterate 4th to 8th values.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you haven't realised that you can have a PL/SQL `BEGIN` ... `END` block, including an exception handler, within a loop.  In fact, anywhere you can have PL/SQL statements you can have a block.

You mention an exception handler, although your code doesn't contain one.  As you say your code goes 'out of the loop', I can only assume it's, well, outside of the `for` loop.  But you can easily add a block, with an exception handler, inside the `for` loop, for example:

```
BEGIN
    for i in 1 .. FILEARRAY.count
    loop
        fileName := FILEARRAY(i); 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (FILEARRAY (i));

        -- Inner block starts at the line below:
        BEGIN
            SELECT FILEID into fileId FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE FILENAME=fileName;
            -- TODO add to PASSARRAY
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                -- TODO add to FAILARRAY
        END;

    end loop
END;
```

This way, if there are 8 values in `FILEARRAY` and no data is found in the table for the third value, the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception gets caught without exiting the loop and the loop then progresses to the fourth value in `FILEARRAY`.

Answer (score 1):

You are handling the exception but you need to avoid the exception.  Try:

```
SELECT NVL(FILEID, "<Put Something here or leave it empty") FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE FILENAME=fileName;
```

That way if it finds a null value in the select it will just pull "" instead.  Then you can check to see if your SELECT returns "" and if so populate your FAILARRAY, otherwise populate PASSARRAY.

Comment: Thanks..Let me check this out and will update if works.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SCHEMA.PR_VALIDATE(
    FILEARRAY IN STRARRAY,
    PASSARRAY OUT STRARRAY,
    FAILARRAY OUT STRARRAY )
IS
  fileName    VARCHAR2 (50);
  l_n_count   NUMBER;
  l_n_file_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. FILEARRAY.count
  LOOP
    fileName := FILEARRAY(i);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (FILEARRAY(i));
    SELECT COUNT(FILEID) INTO l_n_count FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE FILENAME=fileName;
    IF l_n_count   =0 THEN
      failarray(i):='No Value Found';
    elsif l_n_count=1 THEN
      SELECT FILEID INTO l_n_file_id FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE FILENAME=fileName;
      Passarray(i):=l_n_file_id;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Yes thought of this, but it would seem like i need to run the same query again, once to check count and once to take values. right?

Comment: you have to if this is the requirement :)